# LocalStack stuck in "Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready" messages

Tags: docker, localstack

I have tried to run Localstack as it described on its [GitHub page](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) and I've used a command 'pip install localstack' as well as command 'docker-compose up' with docker-compose file from documentation:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  localstack:
    container_name: "${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_NAME-localstack_main}"
    image: localstack/localstack
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:53:53"
      - "127.0.0.1:53:53/udp"
      - "127.0.0.1:443:443"
      - "127.0.0.1:4566:4566"
      - "127.0.0.1:4571:4571"
    environment:
      - SERVICES=${SERVICES- }
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG- }
      - DATA_DIR=${DATA_DIR- }
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=${LAMBDA_EXECUTOR- }
      - LOCALSTACK_API_KEY=${LOCALSTACK_API_KEY- }
      - KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY=${KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY- }
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - HOST_TMP_FOLDER="${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/localstack"
    volumes:
      - "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/localstack:/tmp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

But in both ways I get the same output:

```
localstack_main | 2021-09-21 15:32:26,633 CRIT Supervisor is running as root.  Privileges were not dropped because no user is specified in the config file.  If you intend to run as root, you can set user=root in the config file to avoid this message.
localstack_main | 2021-09-21 15:32:26,645 INFO supervisord started with pid 14
localstack_main | 2021-09-21 15:32:27,650 INFO spawned: 'dashboard' with pid 20
localstack_main | 2021-09-21 15:32:27,653 INFO spawned: 'infra' with pid 21
localstack_main | 2021-09-21 15:32:27,659 INFO success: dashboard entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
localstack_main | 2021-09-21 15:32:27,660 INFO exited: dashboard (exit status 0; expected)
localstack_main | (. .venv/bin/activate; exec bin/localstack start --host)
localstack_main | 2021-09-21 15:32:28,663 INFO success: infra entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
localstack_main | LocalStack version: 0.12.1
localstack_main | Starting local dev environment. CTRL-C to quit.
localstack_main | Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
localstack_main | Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
localstack_main | Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
localstack_main | Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
```

And then nothing appears except these recurring messages.

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Comment: It's not clear which services you use. I have similar issue with just `s3`.

Comment: By the way, how it happenned that you use version `0.12.1` that was released more than a year ago? Have you tried to pull a newer image? I mean `docker-compose pull`

Comment: @AndreySemakin, it's kinda weird, but I found a cause of my certain issue and it was mobile hotspot. When i connect to the internet via hotspot shared with my smartphone, localstack for some unknown for me reasons doesn't start, but when I switch connection to the plain WI-FI at home or office - it works! 
BTW, you're right - it's my mistake. I attached irrelevant docker script and logs because I tried to build different versions of localstack and didn't notice this mismatch

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the solution for everyone, but worth suggesting to try update your Docker version.
I had the same issue and for few days, and then I tried to update my docker version
I use Docker version 20.10.11 on apple silicon and can confirm it works fine. So far, after this update, I did not encounter any new issues with local-stack.

Also this [Github issue](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/3855) suggests deleting your local-stack's volume before each run. It works, however this obviously can't be long term solution, but might be good mitigation when one is in need.

Answer (score -2):

Update your **docker-compose.yml** as below and then run **docker-compose up**. It should work as expected.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  localstack:
    container_name: "${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_NAME-localstack}"
    image: localstack/localstack
    hostname: localstack
    networks:
      - test-net
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"
    environment:
      - SERVICES=s3,sqs,cloudformation,iam,cloudwatch
      - DEBUG=1
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=docker-reuse
      - LAMBDA_REMOTE_DOCKER=false
      - LAMBDA_REMOVE_CONTAINERS=true
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - HOST_TMP_FOLDER=${TMPDIR}
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
networks:
  test-net:
    external: false
    driver: bridge
    name: test-net
```

Comment: What's the part that makes the difference?